# How to optionally apply some plugins using Kotlin DSL and plugins block with gradle and android

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to apply some plugins optionally to improve build time in development time.

I mean I have this:

`app/gradle.build.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}
```

But I dont want to apply firebase crashlytics plugin all the time (and other plugins like perf monitor), but if I try to access the `project` inside of the `plugins` block I get:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")

    if (!project.hasProperty("build_fast")) {
        id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    }
}
```

I get:

```
'val Build_gradle.project: Project' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary
```

So my questions are:

1. I can access the System env variables with `System.getenv("CI")` but replacing those values from android studio is a little bit hacky currently to me, someone can show a way to update those variables?
2. How can I do it using `project.hasPropperty("")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The plugins DSL is limited in what you can and can't do. This is documented in [Limitations of the plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations).

To conditionally apply a plugin, you must use [`Project.apply(T)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Plugin.html#apply-T-):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") apply false
}
```

The `apply false` is necessary because we don't want to apply the plugin, but we want the types or classes that are available from that plugin so we can programmatically apply the plugin in a type safe manner.

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") apply false
}

apply<CrashlyticsPlugin>()
```

> I can access the System env variables with `System.getenv("CI")` but replacing those values from android studio is a little bit hacky currently to me, someone can show a way to update those variables?

You can't update the environment (`System.getenv()`), it is a unmodifiable map.

> How can I do it using `project.hasPropperty("")`

Use that as a conditional which you have done:

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") apply false
}

if (!hasProperty("build_fast")) {
    apply<CrashlyticsPlugin>()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it and come back when I have a response :)