# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Could not find method getMetad

Tags: android, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Could not find method getMetadataByConfig() for arguments [] on task ':app:processDebugManifest' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gradle's Configuration Cache and Huawei's AgConnect plugin at the same time, then the problem might be due to this plugin. See: https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0202743615441540593

As a temporary solution until plugin maintainers fix the plugin, consider disabling Gradle's Configuration Cache or applying AgConnect plugin conditionally. For example don't apply it during development and only apply it while releasing.

Here is some sample code to apply the plugin conditionally. All code in Kotlin (kts). Helper functions:

```
fun Project.isReleaseTask(): Boolean =
    gradle.startParameter.taskRequests.toString().toLowerCase().contains("release")

fun Project.isPublishTask(): Boolean =
    gradle.startParameter.taskRequests.toString().toLowerCase().contains("publish")

val Project.isHuaweiPluginEnabled: Boolean
    get() = properties["com.yourcompany.enableHuaweiPlugin]?.toString().toBoolean()
```

Then, If you have a convention plugin:

```
class MyConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        maybeApplyHuaweiPlugin()
        
        // other configurations 
    }

    private fun Project.maybeApplyHuaweiPlugin() {
        if (isHuaweiPluginEnabled || isReleaseTask() || isPublishTask()) {
            pluginManager.apply("com.huawei.agconnect")
        }
    }
}
```

OR: if you don't have convention plugin:

app/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.huawei.agconnect") apply false
}

if (isHuaweiPluginEnabled || isReleaseTask() || isPublishTask()) {
    pluginManager.apply("com.huawei.agconnect")
}
```

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: @mustafa can this be done inside the app's build gradle? currently the agconnect is placed inside the dependencies in the project's build gradle. if not, can you also please provide an example how to do so?

Comment: @chitgoks I added sample code for conditionally applying the plugin. It's basically an if condition based on your criteria. I also added a local build flag so that you can enable it locally if you need it with "-Pcom.yourcompany.enableHuaweiPlugin=true" parameter. 

If you use remote build-cache: consider using the same configuration locally and on your CI, so that they produce the same cache keys&entries.

Also see other answers on conditionally applying plugins as there are other ways as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62586954/2708768

Comment: ahh. i dont have a problem with the app/build.gradle. My case, I actually placed the apply plugin in the flavor. My issue is in the project/build.gradle. is that possible? I placed it in the dependencies block.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue recently while trying to upgrade our project's Gradle to 8.4 and AGP to 8.1.2, and here's what I did.

1. Upgrade to the latest `agcp` version(currently 1.9.1.301)
2. Add the following line into `build.gradle` file of app module [according to this post](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0202743615441540593)

```
agcp{
    manifest = false
}
```

Besides, this plugin will enable a APM tool by default, you can disable it by adding `apmsInstrumentationEnabled=false` to your project's `gradle.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

I commented out one line in gradle.properties:

```
#org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

This helped me.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76157049/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).